# Leer datos del csv doble comilla en python

Tags: python, csv, python-2.x

Estoy intentando leer datos de un archivo **csv**, en especial númericos pero estoy obteniendo un resultado inesperado.

ejemplo:

csv: `"17.913,92";"17.913,92";`

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
   reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
   for row in reader
      value = row
```

**value** tiene guardado `u'"17.913,92"'`, pero necesito `"17.913,92"`. como leer estos datos sin las comas, y sin hacer algo como cortar los caracteres sobrantes `""`

gracias

Comment: Hola. Lo que debería tener `value` según tu código es una lista y no una cadena como muestras en el ejemplo. ¿Estás seguro que ese es el resultado?

Comment: bueno es un ejemplo, en el cual cada valor en cada fila  se esta leyendo de esa forma, el csv  es mas largo e incluye los headers.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
reader = csv.reader(cvsfile, delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
```